# Sitecore 9.1 Installation Error

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, installation, powershell

The installation for Sitecore 9.1.0 is stuck at step number 50. This is what I get in the System Event Logs as 3 separate errors.

> Errors were encountered in the procedure
>   'dbo.__DeleteAllReportingData' during compilation of the object.
>   Either the containment option of the database 'xp901_Reporting' was
>   changed, or this object was present in model db and the user tried to
>   create a new contained database.
>
> Errors were encountered in the procedure 'dbo.ReduceMetricsTable'
>   during compilation of the object. Either the containment option of the
>   database 'xp901_Reporting' was changed, or this object was present in
>   model db and the user tried to create a new contained database.
>
> Errors were encountered in the procedure 'dbo.ReduceSegmentMetrics'
>   during compilation of the object. Either the containment option of the
>   database 'xp901_Reporting' was changed, or this object was present in
>   model db and the user tried to create a new contained database.

Previously, I have installed Sitecore 9.0.1 and 9.0.2 on the same machine.
Any pointers?

The PowerShell script is stuck at this point

```
[ShardingTool - Create]:[Path] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xp910.xconnect\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe
        *** Welcome to Sitecore xDB Collection SQL Sharding Deployment Tool ***
        Tool was run with the following configuration:
        Operation: create
        SQL server connection:
        Server name: DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS
        User: sa
        Integrated security: False
        Connect Timeout: 15
        Database edition: Basic
        Shard map manager database name: xp901_Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager
        Shard map names: ContactIdShardMap, DeviceProfileIdShardMap, ContactIdentifiersIndexShardMap
        Shard number: 2
        Shard name prefix: xp910_Xdb.Collection.Shard
        Shard name suffix:
        Dacpac file path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xp901.xconnect\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.Sql.dacpac
        Creating database xp910_Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager
        Created Shard Map Manager
```

Comment: This is a long shot but is it possible you installed Sitecore 9.0.1 previously with the name "xp910" and then deleted it without deleting the databases?

Comment: I don't have such database before and I always delete before installing fresh version.

Comment: What version of SQL are you on?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 SP 2 -  version -> 13.0.5026.0

Comment: I've started getting this on my machine as well, did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore 9.1 requires you to enable contained database authentication.

You just need to run the following command on your SQL Server Management Studio:

```
sp_configure ‘contained database authentication’, 1;
GO

RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Comment: I have run this several times but no progress

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the file path for the Dacpac, you might be pointing to 9.0.1 files on the 9.1.0 installation. Can you double-check this?

Also, 9.0.1 and 9.0.2 use SIF 1 I think, while 9.1 uses SIF 2. It might be you're using the wrong version of SIF to install?

Comment: That's not possible as the Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe is deployed / extracted during the installation process. I am using SIF 2

Comment: Looking at your error message there's a configuration for SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe. 
Dacpac file path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xp**901**.xconnect\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.Sql.dacpac
The path you're running it from is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xp**910**.xconnect\
They do not match.

Answer (score 0):

According to Sitecore compatibility table, Sitecore 9.1 can only be installed on SQL 2016 sp2 and above, Sitecore 9.0 can only be installed on SQL 2016 sp1 and under. Make sure your SQL server version meet the 9.1 requirement.
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164

Comment: I do have SQL 2016 SP2 installed, this didn't work.